# consolidate where clause sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select statement that is not really efficient since I am using union all to make it work instead of properly using parentheses or 'or'. Please let me know if you know of a better way to combine these statements:

```
select * from apples_2014
where value is null
and (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 <= '2014-01-21')

union all

select * from apples_2014
where value is null
and (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 is null)

union all 

select * from apples_2014
where value is null
and (date_2 <= '2014-01-21' and date_1 is null)

union all

select * from apples_2014
where value is null
and (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)
```

Comment: Do you want the result with the existing duplicates, or with each row just once?

Comment: It looks like you should consider using the NVL function (looks like it could address the first three query blocks).  Your last query block has the potential of having some intersection with the other query blocks (no constraints on date_2 or date_1).  Are you sure the last query block is a distinct set of records from the other ones?

Comment: I don't want duplicates. I like Gordons solution I will try it now. Patrick the NVL function sounds interesting. How would that work with Gordons code? The last query is distinct from the others.

Comment: This way:                                                            (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 <= '2014-01-21')
OR (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 is null)
OR (date_2 <= '2014-01-21' and date_1 is null)
OR (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)

would correspond with this: 

(NVL(date_1, '2014-01-21') <= '2014-01-21' and NVL(date_2, '2014-01-21')  <= '2014-01-21')
    OR (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)

Comment: Ok cool Ill add that in too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is quite similar to what you want:

```
select *
from apples_2014
where value is null and
      ((date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 <= '2014-01-21') or
       (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 is null) or
       (date_2 <= '2014-01-21' and date_1 is null) or
       (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)
      );
```

There is a difference, though.  Your query will return a row multiple times sometimes, once for each condition.  This will return a row only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from apples_2014
    where 
    value is null
    and (
    (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 <= '2014-01-21')
OR (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 is null)
    OR (date_2 <= '2014-01-21' and date_1 is null)
    OR (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from apples_2014
where value is null
   and (
           (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 <= '2014-01-21')
           OR (date_1 <= '2014-01-21' and date_2 is null)
           OR (date_2 <= '2014-01-21' and date_1 is null)
           OR (date_3 <= '2014-01-21' and date_3 is not null)
       )
```